# Unable to set default value in Activeadmin Addons Plugin for ajax search_select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin_addons plugin in rails active admin for populating select dropdown using ajax, for that i used Select2 (search_select given by activeadmin_addons). The add on is working fine but i am unable to set default value for select dropdown when the active admin form loads in case of edit form scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got better alternative. I used Activeadmin::AjaxFilter gem, for populating dropdown using ajax, and it also provides setting default value of field while editing.

Documentation of above gem is not good so i will give you some tips :

For Ajax request response should be like :

```
[{"id":"hello","manufacturer":"hello"}]
```

here "id" is what you set in "value_field" (options) and

here "manufacturer" is what you set in "search_fields" (options).

Sample to set default value in edit form in active admin .

```
form do |f|
  f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
  f.object.updated_by = current_user.id
  f.object.virtual_manufacturer =            f.object.medicine_manufacturer.try(:id) unless f.object.new_record?
  f.inputs "Medicine" do
    input :strength
    input :virtual_manufacturer, label: "Manufacturer", as: :ajax_select, data: {
      url: autocomplete_medicinemaster_manufacturer_admin_medicinemasters_path,
      search_fields: [:manufacturer],
  }
end
```

Here i have prefilled values for virtual_manufacturer. After form edit form is loaded, it will automatically hit the api with default value.

This gem is nice alternative for autocomplete in active admin select dropdown.